MUI how to reduce bundle size with vite
I'm using MUI and MUI X for the datagrid.
Even if I use imports correctly (at least I think!) I can't reduce the bundle size which is currently over 2MB.


I read the guide to minimize the bundle size:
MUI minimize bundle size
but it seems not to work for me.
For example: is there a way to prevent the entire x-data-grid module from loading on every page, and instead have it download only on the pages where I actually use it?
